# How do I establish a COM port on virtual machine that points at the USB port of the host desktop?

Tags: powershell, serial-port, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am using Hyper-V Manager on my Windows 8.1 device to host a virtual machine. As it turns out, there is no way to enable your COM ports through the user interface, instead you must use Windows PowerShell ([as described here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2013/10/31/hyper-v-generation-2-virtual-machines-part-5.aspx) and shown below).

[image]

I have followed the directions provided in the link above, and I can see the VM COM ports (1 & 2) listed in the device manager of the VM. I can point at the VM COM ports with the kernel debugger in WinDbg (running on the VM). Finally, I am trying to kernel debug a peripheral device physically plugged into the USB port of the **HOST** machine (COM4).

---

How do I map the **VM** COM ports to the **HOST** machine?

Comment: You don't. Mapping physical COM ports to virtual machines is still not supported AFAIK. You could try something like [Network Serial Port Kit](http://www.fabulatech.com/network-serial-port-kit.html), though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the VM via the "**Remote Desktop Connection**" application.

- There is a "**Show Options**" button in the lower-left corner.
- There will be a tab labelled "**Local Resources**"
- There is a box titled "**Local devices and resources**"
- Click the "**More...**" button.
- Check the "**Ports**" check-box.
- Finally, sign in to your VM under the "**General**" tab.

Now you can access the resources of your local machine in your VM.